# How can I make the picture smaller in the picture box without affecting the coordination?

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, zooming

I want to let the user define the area that they want to extract the text, but for the line item, the picture is too large and it make the rectangle cannot include the whole table.

I found a solution that able to smaller the picture but the coordinate also changed. For example, I draw the rectangle area at the "Malarvili" but the rectangle coordinate is not same as what I had drawn. Because of this, the extracted text is wrong.
[image: Example 1]

So I want to know any solution to make the picture becomes smaller in the picturebox without affecting the original rectangle coordinate? Or using my original solution which is using the "autosize" without changing the picture size, but I have also facing a problem which is when i drawing the rectangle to the right, the scrollbar will not autoscroll and it makes me cannot draw the rectangle to the end of the right.
[image: My current solution but the scrollbar will not auto scroll to right when the mouse is moving to right]

Any solution to solve these problems? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the ratios (x and y axis) between the resize image (`pictureBox` with `StretchImage` mode) and the original image, and then calculate back the rectangle for original image from the rectangle you drawed in the pictureBox using these ratios.

```
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
ratio_X = (double) pictureBox.Width/original_image;
ratio_Y = (double) pictureBox.Height/original_image;

//suppose you have the rect drawed in the pictureBox: pictureBox_rect
//now make a rect for original_image
Rectangle original_rect = new Rect((int)pictureBox_rect.X * ratio_X, 
                                   (int)pictureBox_rect.Y * ratio_Y, 
                                   (int)pictureBox_rect.Width * ratio_X, 
                                   (int)pictureBox_rect.Height * ratio_Y)
```